# Resizing pixel resolution after interpolation using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, resolution

I did kriging spatial interpolation using climatic point file.

After doing interpolation, how can I resize the pixel resolution to pixel resolution of the NDVI data.

NDVI image's pixel resolution is 250m.

Answer (score 3):

Raster resampling is what you're looking for. Check:

- [ArcGIS Desktop Help 9.3 - Resample](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Resample)

> Changes the cell size of a raster.

- [ArcGIS Desktop Help 9.3 - Cell size and resampling in analysis](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Cell_size_and_resampling_in_analysis)

> Different raster datasets do not need to be stored using the same cell
>   resolution. But when you are processing between multiple datasets, the
>   cell resolution, like the registration, needs to be the same. When
>   multiple raster datasets are input into any ArcGIS Spatial Analyst
>   function and their resolutions are different, one or more of the input
>   datasets will be automatically resampled using the nearest neighbor
>   assignment to the coarsest resolution from input datasets.